# Unable to recognise little-endian format

Tags: q#, quantum-fourier-transform

I'm told that the input register is in little-endian format. But the vscode gives me error telling me that it is wrong argument for QFT even after using a suitable converter. Am I missing something here?

```
    operation Task31 (qs : Qubit[]) : Unit {
        X(qs[Length(qs)-1]);
        ApplyReversedOpBE(QFT, qs);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to cast your qubit array as type [LittleEndian](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.arithmetic.littleendian?view=qsharp-preview):

```
let LEArray = LittleEndian(qs);
```

A good example of this is in the QuantumKatas under [Quantum Phase Estimation](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumKatas/blob/8621795b0d8e2005ff7037f814718669b84697e8/PhaseEstimation/ReferenceImplementation.qs#L81).